# Tcsh-like history scrolling for commands?

Tags: command-line

In the command minibuffer (Pardon my emacs, I don't know what it's actually called), `C-p` and `C-n` go to the previous and next command in my history. Is there a way to make them behave like `M-n` and `M-p` in `tcsh`? Those will take you to the previous and next commands matching the current prefix. (The prefix being everything before the current cursor position). If that isn't possible, can vim emulate the `zsh` behavior of scrolling through options beginning with the same command / word?

If I do:

```
:edit ~/.vimrc
:read !ls
:e
```

and then hit `<c-p>`, I'd like it to complete `:edit ~/.vimrc` not `:read !ls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be `<UP>` and `<Down>` in cmdline-mode:

```
                        *c_<Up>* *c_Up*
<Up>  recall older command-line from history, whose beginning
      matches the current command-line (see below).
      {not available when compiled without the |+cmdline_hist|
      feature}
                            *c_<Down>* *c_Down*
<Down>  recall more recent command-line from history, whose beginning
        matches the current command-line (see below).
        {not available when compiled without the |+cmdline_hist|
        feature}
```

And you can remap those if you want:

```
cnoremap <C-p> <UP>
cnoremap <C-n> <Down>
```